# Authentication error in openstack with new domain

Tags: openstack

My openstack was working fine with the `default` domain. Today I created another domain `domainTwo` using

```
openstack create doamin domainTwo
```

created a new project `domainTwoProject`

```
openstack project create --domain domainTwo --description "Admin Project" domainTwoProject
```

and a new user `domainTwoAdmin`

```
openstack user create --domain domainTwo --password-prompt domainTwoAdmin
```

Created the admin role:

```
openstack role create admin
```

Added the admin role to the `domainTwoProject` project and user:

```
openstack role add --project domainTwoProject --user domainTwoAdmin admin
```

Now when I am trying to login with horizon dashboard in domain `domainTwo` with username `domainTwoAdmin` and Password `XXXXXXXXXX` it  works perfectly. When I am trying it with `source admins-openrc.sh`

The content of admin-openrc.sh is:

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=XXXXX
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX:35357/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

after that I run `openstack token issue` and I got desired output.
However when I am trying this command with `source admin-domaintwo.sh` I am not getting desired output.

The content  of admin-domaintwo.sh is:

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=domainTwoProject
export OS_TENANT_NAME=domainTwoProject
export OS_USERNAME=domainTwoAdmin
export OS_PASSWORD=XXXXX
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX:35357/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

i got error

```
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-IDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

Comment: what error message you get , may be you need a fresh shell with previous env variables cleared

Comment: i tried,in fresh shell.

Comment: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: I am having same issue.. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you find the solution or not but I want to provide an approach that will help to solve this types of problem. I also face this problem and found solution.

From your comment,It seems that you are having problem of authentication. Authentication is handled by keystone component of openstack.
So to find what is exactly problematic we need to check each related components log messages.

First check the access log of httpd, I am giving command for continuous view of logs,you can open this in another tab.

`tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log`

now check the error message of httpd

`tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`

check keystone log

`tail -f /var/log/keystone/keystone.log`

Try to figure out what goes wrong. Also check the configuration file of horizon local settings.

`/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings`

specially `OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL` this field, and `OPENSTACK_API_VERSIONS`,`OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN`,`OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE`. 
Double check you IDENTITY VERSION and Keystone endpoint url version,check if versions are identical in both dashboard configuration and service endpoints.

This is research process which will help you find out what is wrong about authentication.

If you start over the installation procedure,in each step verify the operation for each components like first install keystone and check if it okay and go on. This will help to identify and troubleshoot further problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
openstack role add --domain domainTwo --user domainTwoAdmin admin

openstack role add --project domainTwoProject --user domainTwoAdmin admin
```